# Let $f=\sum_1^n a_j \chi_{E_j}$ be a simple function, compute $\int |f|^p=\int |\sum_1^n a_j \chi_{E_j}|^p$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, measure-theory

Let $f=\sum_1^n a_j \chi_{E_j}$ be a simple function where $\mu(E_j)\lt \infty$.

I want to show that $f\in L^p$, but I don't know how to compute $\int |f|^p=\int |\sum_1^n a_j \chi_{E_j}|^p$.

How can I integrate this function? I would greatly appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: If $f$ takes the value $a_j$ at $E_J$, then $|f|^p$ will take the value $|a_j|^p$  at $E_J$.